# Print the pixel array from a bmp image

Tags: c++, c, bitmap

So, I have a 24 bmp image saved in the memory and I want to print the array of pixels,  I am using **BITMAPFILEHEADER** and **BITMAPINFOHEADER** for figuring out the header and info header of the bitmap, however when looking up documentation I see that the file header has a member called `bfOffBits`   that should show the starting location of the pixels and I can get the size of the pixel array through info_header->Height and Width.

My issues is that when looking at the wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header) page I need to figure out the padding bytes size and the actual pixel bytes. But my image has a Width of 1152, I get that by printing:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER* bitmap_info_header = NULL;
bitmap_info_header = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(file_info->file_address + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
printf("Width %ld \n", bitmap_info_header->biWidth);
```

and i'm not sure if that means there is no padding? Also when starting to read the pixels I start from :

```
typedef struct 
{
    HANDLE file_handle;
    HANDLE mapping_handle;
    BYTE* file_address;
    DWORD file_size;
}FILE_INFO;
 file_info->file_address[bitmap_file_header->bfOffBits]
```

And I am not sure that is correct because reading through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader I find a "Colour table " that I haven't identified.

I just want to find out if there is padding or not and if I read from the correct address, as I get them mixed up a lot. thank you !

Comment: You might show a bit more than those unrelated snippets. In your link you find a formulat to calculate the stride between rows. What is your result? Is it different than what you got from `biwidth`?

Comment: The link mentions under what condition a colour table is included and where. Without even the faintest trace of an information about your image we cannot tell if you should have one or not.

Comment: Yes, the stride and `biWidth`  are different, also the image has the  `biCompression` equal to BI_RGB and I know is immediately after the info_header but is it from the adress starting the pixel array ? Or those the `bitmap_file_reader-> bfOffBits` jumps over it ?

Comment: It's not really that much about the code but about my logic/reading comprehension, I just don't know what is right or wrong and reading the documentations just confuse me even more

Comment: It would make things a lot easier if you showed the content of all the fields in your bitmap. This would help identifying the colour table.

Comment: Actually you mix multiple questions. Padding and Colour table are not related. Any question at SO should only contain 1 question.

Comment: When calculating the stride you need to be aware that this is counted in bytes, not in pixels. If pixel*bytesperpixel != stride, you have some padding per line.